# Why did Sinon act strangely when Kirito grabbed her tail?

Tags: sword-art-online

I noticed in an episode of Sword Art Online II (Calibur arc) that Sinon (a Cait Sith) reacted strangely when Kirito grabbed her tail. Silica (also a Cath Sith) noticed this but it seems that she too (just like me) has no idea. What happened [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzxbodu3AnY)?

Comment: Watching the clip, you'd get the impression that she reacted like he was looking up her skirt or something. If you notice, when the camera focuses on Silica after Sinon's threat, Silica is holding her tail in her hand.

Comment: @PaulRowe - It wouldn't surprise me if it felt like a butt-pinch, which would both produce that reaction when someone else does it, and not be an issue when you do it to yourself.

Comment: @Bobson Considering that they're in a VR game and people don't have tails IRL, that's probably how the signal was sent to the brain.

Comment: @Bobson Sexual innuendo seems like the most likely scenario. No game No Life also featured Angel like creatures who felt pleasure when someone rubbed their Wings. Seem like a fan service gag to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following is quoted from Sword Art Online Book 8: Early and Late, page 221

> The triangular ears and tail unique to the Cait Sith race were of
>   course organs human don’t have, however, they could sense the feeling
>   using an unknown mechanism. Being grabbed hard by a player who
>   wasn’t aware of the fact would cause a «super weird feeling»——
>   Silica’s explanation——for that reason, the reaction was always very
>   amusing.

This quote actually shows us a few things:

1. Why Kirito pulled her tail in the first place: it's "amusing"
2. What it feels like: "a super weird feeling" cause by sensentations from an organ humans don't normally have - similar to the wings in ALO, I might add
3. Why Silica looks at her tail in the YouTube clip: calling it a "super weird feeling" was her description, so she clearly knows how it feels. In other words, it's likely that someone (possibly Kirito, since he seems to enjoy it so much) has done the same thing to her.

I've added the picture of this scene from the light novel just for reference.

[image: Kirito Pulls Sinon's Tail]

Comment: I'll add on.  The tail does have to correspond to somewhere on the body, and stimulus IS transmitted through the amu-sphere to the brain.  The tail can be a sensitive area, and thus I leave the determination of what the program decided the tail was in relation to the host body, up to the community.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it likely causes extreme discomfort or a strange feeling, due to actual humans not having these body parts, but the Amusphere still transmits that feeling. Much like a real-life cat getting their tail pulled, but perhaps less painful.

Answer (score -1):

In many anime or Japanese pop culture, a cat-person's tail and ears are extremely sensitive and considered a "place only touched with permission". I think you get it now.

Answer (score -5):

Maybe its because grabbing her tail didnt give her feeling of having her tail being grabbed due to the fact she doesnt have one, and the game made feel it in the spot where her tail would have been-her anus